# How to create a segue to another view controller through search bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

How would I create a segue to another view controller when `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` is executed?

Comment: (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*) searchContact { //push to another ViewController}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create segue from controller to controller. (Note: Not from any controller's control, but from controller).
2. Set segue identifier.
3. Call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"your segue identifier" sender: self];` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method.

Comment: it's **[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"your segue identifier" sender:self];**

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {

   yourviewcontroller *name = [[yourviewcontroller alloc]initwithnibname@"yourviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:name animated:YES];



 }
```